# SoapUI: Message does not conform to configured policy

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

We're using SoapUI. We've imported a WSDL and created a test request

However we are met with the error:

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <env:Code>
            <env:Value>env:Sender</env:Value>
         </env:Code>
         <env:Reason>
            <env:Text xml:lang="en">com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Message does not conform to configured policy [ AuthenticationTokenPolicy(S) ]:  No Security Header found</env:Text>
         </env:Reason>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

However we are not provided with that information in the documentation

Any suggestions as to what is needed to get this over the line? Stumped!

[image]

This is what SoapUI has

[image]

I try and follow [getting an WS-security error while trying to send SOAP request toweb service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37066777/getting-an-ws-security-error-while-trying-to-send-soap-request-toweb-service) but I get

```
Receiver Requirement for Digested Password has not been met
```

Comment: The *com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Message does not conform to configured policy [ AuthenticationTokenPolicy(S) ]:  No Security Header found* error seems to be quite clear. It's expecting a security header. Where did you get the WSDL from? And the documentation? You might be calling a newer version of a service using older reference material.

Comment: WSDL is from the server I'm trying to authenticate against as well as the documentation. I understand it needing a security header but I can't see anywhere on what specifically is needed in the documentation or WSDL. Actually there is this: "All web service responses listed below are based on the raw XML with no security headers added. Refer to the Web Service Security for details on the security headers, encryption, and signing of SOAP messages." but the link is 404

Comment: You could try playing with [various security options in SoapUI](https://www.soapui.org/docs/soapui-projects/ws-security/), but I suggest you reach out to the service owners and ask for the missing parts of the documentation, or to give you a complete request example. A SOAP web service is like a black box if you don't have a proper WSDL or proper documentation at hand.